# Error in getting data from JSON Object in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to get data from from the json object

`{[{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}]}`

But getting error that is mentioned below

```
const myObj ={[{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}]};
const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);
console.log(myObjStr);
```

getting this error
`SyntaxError: /src/index.js: Unexpected token (1:171)`

Comment: That's not a valid object.

Comment: but i am getting from already created json format. how can i make it valid or remove first and last curly braces.

Comment: and how can i get name from it

Comment: Give the Array a key is one way to make it valid removing the outer braces is the other. How to remove leading and trailing characters of a string has been answered multiple times already.

Comment: Give the Array a key how? @Adriani6

Comment: @PuneetKansal Type it in? `{ key: [{"....`

Comment: @PuneetKansal where are you getting this JSON from? It's not valid JSON data, you need to remove the outer most array square brackets, or give that array a key, e.g. `{ someKey: [...] }`

Comment: @PuneetKansal: Why are you looking for patch instead of fix the actual problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the JSON you are passing to stringify. You can always validate your JSON with some online editor to check its format. 
You can check

`{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}`

or

`[{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}]`

Comment: i understand  that i am getting wrong jsonobject. i am getting it from online database table. so how can i resolve it in the program.

Answer (score 2):

You have created an object without a key that's causing the error

```js
const myObj1 =[{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}];

const myObj2 ={key: [{"Checkit":"list","st":[{"name":"Mike","ID":1,"Problem":"France - 6 Months"}]}]};


const myObjStr1 = JSON.stringify(myObj1);
const myObjStr2 = JSON.stringify(myObj2);

console.log(myObjStr1);
console.log(myObjStr2);
```